# Recommended way to register custom serializer with StateManager

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In the pre-GA version of Service Fabric I was registering a custom serializer like this:

```
    protected override IReliableStateManager CreateReliableStateManager()
    {
        IReliableStateManager result = new ReliableStateManager(
            new ReliableStateManagerConfiguration(
                onInitializeStateSerializersEvent: InitializeStateSerializers));

        return result;
    }

    private Task InitializeStateSerializers()
    {
        StateManager.TryAddStateSerializer(new KFOBinarySerializer());
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
```

However, the `CreateReliableStateManager` method was removed in the GA version. I've struggled to get something working in its place. Currently I'm calling

`StateManager.TryAddStateSerializer(new KFOBinarySerializer());`

from within the service's `RunAsync` method, which appears to work fine.

1. What is the recommended way to register a custom serializer?
2. `TryAddStateSerializer` is deprecated. Anyone know if this is because custom serialization support will go away or if it will simply be supported through some other mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the state manager in the `StatefulService`'s constructor (full example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612592.aspx)):

```
class MyService : StatefulService
{
   public MyService(StatefulServiceContext serviceContext) 
       : base(serviceContext, CreateReliableStateManager()) { }

    private static IReliableStateManager CreateReliableStateManager() { ... }
}
```

Regarding the deprecated API, Microsoft says it's safe to use, but it will change in the future.