# How do I register a custom serializer in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have found couple of references to the "TryAddStateSerializer" method but it appears to be deprecated, and the examples provided don't seem to work anyway including this one [GitHub Azure content](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/commit/78e595701b4117371074db450eb0c5692914d804).

How an I supposed to register my Custom serializer?

Comment: As far as I saw, there is no other way to do it. But you have nothing to worry about. If this method will be removed, it will be not so difficult to adjust your code.

Comment: Yes but they seem to have adjusted the code so the method no longer works.

Comment: I run a test from [this](https://github.com/vturecek/metric-reliable-collections) repo with custom serializer implementation and look like everything works fine. I have the latest SF SDK. Do you receive any exceptions?

Comment: TryAddStateSerializer should still be the supported way. Can you provide more info about what you are seeing? Possible dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784086/recommended-way-to-register-custom-serializer-with-statemanager Docs showing recommended pattern here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt612592.aspx

Comment: You should list this as an answer, there are a number similar implementations but none of them work. This one does thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TryAddStateSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt612592.aspx) is currently the only way to do it. The API may change in the future but it is safe to use today.